# a confusion in a sentence between the superlative and comparative form

Tags: adjectives, superlatives

I have a confusion;

Do we say "one of the largest players"  or  "one of the larger players"?

Comment: Welcome to the ell. Please click on the edit icon to include the context.

Comment: Either, depending on what you want to say. *Larger* means relatively large; *largest* means, metaphorically, at or near the top of the ladder.

Comment: What about the presence of "the"? I think that the largest is the correct one, but I found in some writings "the larger", so I am asking if there are exceptions.

Comment: *The* would be usual there, but I don't know whether it's mandatory. Swan does say that after *one of* a noun phrase must have a determiner (e.g., *the*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on context.

If you were referring to a group of tall players, you might say:

> He is **one of the largest** players.

But if you were referring to a full range of players from short to tall, you might say:

> He is **one of the larger** players.